# Querying targetTypes in Schema Extensions of Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The documentation page at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension did not sport the usual "Supports $filter" as on other objects so I had to give it a try:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions/?$filter=targetTypes/any(c:c eq 'User')
```

Listing status=Available and eg targetTypes=User would be handy in our case without retrieving the whole list beforehand (Graph Explorer for the demo tenant has already a nice long list). I take there's then (at least at the moment) no way around just grabbing the whole list even though I only need a subset or targetTypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. We do support filtering on status, but not on targetTypes currently (although it's weird that we don't error that that filter is not supported, and simply return everything).  This is something that we could add.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Is this supported now (after over 5 years)? Doesn't look like it...

Comment: still appears to not work.  just returns everything